# split http data json

Tags: json, tcl, eggdrop

I have a http query from here: http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0084787&plot=full&language=1&r=json

how can I split this?

I might for all vairbles , Title, Year, Rated, Genre, ... Language, imdbRating, imdbVotes etc..

```
bind pub - !imdb imdb

proc imdb { nick uhost hand chan text} {
    package require http 
    set id [lindex [split $text] 0];
    set url "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=$id&plot=short&r=json"
    set data [::http::data [::http::geturl $url]]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Tcllib JSON (https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/json/json.html)?

Comment: no, how make this?

Answer (score 3):

First off, don't put your `package require`s in the procedure. That's inelegant. Secondly, don't forget to `http::cleanup` the token or you'll get some leaked resources (just memory, but it can add up over time).

The JSON response can be converted into a Tcl dictionary with the json package's `json2dict` command. (The package is part of tcllib, in case you've not installed that.) Once you've got a dictionary, use `dict with` to open it up as individual variables; that's the easiest way for your case.

Here's the result, with quite a few comments too.

```
# package requires go at the top *BY CONVENTION* so they're easy to see
package require http
package require json

bind pub - !imdb imdb

proc imdb { nick uhost hand chan text} {
    # Parse what the user said; this is shorter, especially when working with more variables

    lassign [split $text] id

    # Talk to the web service and parse the result
    # NOTE that this doesn't handle errors such as a non-existent ID...

    set tok [http::geturl "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=$id&plot=short&r=json"]
    set data [json::json2dict [http::data $tok]]
    http::cleanup $tok

    # Work with the results

    dict with data { # <<<< Magical!
        puthelp "Movie: $Title ($Year)"
    }
}
```